# Python requests: missing content-length response

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests, head

Python requests does not returns the content-length header what I can get with curl.

```py
def get_headers(url):
    response = requests.head(url)
    return response.headers
```

Response:

```
{'Server': 'nginx/1.17.9', 'Date': 'Sun, 24 May 2020 19:09:02 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="introduction - Sia API Documentation.html"', 'Skynet-File-Metadata': '{"filename":"introduction - Sia API Documentation.html"}', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'skynet-file-metadata', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

I also tried with requests.get, but also not working:
`response = requests.get(url, stream=True)`

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the headers that are returned, you will notice:

`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

If you compare the headers that are sent, however, using httpbin, you might notice that Requests also sends Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate. If you remove that header, e.g.,

`r = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': None})`

Then you get your Content-Length header.

Source: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3953